# SQL Subquery Where Not Exists Before Today

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, grouping

I have a database of IP addresses that are being updated continually. I need to know how many unique IP addresses have been added today that haven't been added before today.

I have tried to do this with a subquery - but the query now grinds along taking minutes as I am dealing with millions of records.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT 
   visitDate,
   COUNT(*) AS TotalDistinctIPs,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CustomerIPs
   -- SUM(CustomerIPs Where does not exist in prior day!)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        V.ip,
        CAST(V.visitdate AS DATE) AS visitdate,
        [type]
        FROM IP_Addresses V
    ) x
GROUP BY
    visitdate
ORDER BY visitdate DESC
```

Here is some example data that I have annotated to illustrate what I am trying to do here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IP_Addresses](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IP] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [visitDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IP_Addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ON
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (1, N'192.168.0.1', N'C', CAST(0x0000A33B00A63920 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (2, N'192.168.0.2', N'C', CAST(0x0000A33B00C72EA0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (3, N'192.168.0.4', N'P', CAST(0x0000A33A011C5F38 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (4, N'192.168.0.5', N'C', CAST(0x0000A33A00C72EA0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (5, N'192.168.0.6', N'C', CAST(0x0000A33900F89EE0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (6, N'192.168.0.7', N'C', CAST(0x0000A33800A63920 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (7, N'192.168.0.8', N'P', CAST(0x0000A33700875D84 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (8, N'192.168.0.1', N'C', CAST(0x0000A3360089CA9C AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] ([id], [IP], [type], [visitDate]) VALUES (9, N'192.168.0.5', N'C', CAST(0x0000A336006660FC AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[IP_Addresses] OFF
```

The Target is to add a New Customer IPs column. This column must contain a count of Unique IP Addresses that haven't visited on a previous day.

Using this dataset as an example - the desired output would look like this:

```
visitDate TotalDistinctIPs CustomerIPs New Customer IPs
2014-05-30         2        2              1
2014-05-29         2        1              0
2014-05-28         1        1              1
2014-05-27         1        1              1
2014-05-26         1        0              0
2014-05-25         2        2              2
```

Row: 1 (visitDate 2014-05-30)
id = 1: Is not a new customer (see id = 8)
id = 2: is a new customer (does not exist in the days previous)

Row: 2 (visitDate 2014-05-29)
id = 3: Is not a customer (type is 'P')
id = 4: Is not a new customer (previous visit see id = 9)

Row: 3 (visitDate 2014-05-28)
id = 5: Is a new customer

and so on...

Thanks in advance to the dbo.Genius that cracks this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you don't mean "today", you mean on any given date in the past.  You can do this by sequentially numbering the visits in your subquery.  Note that the following changes the subquery from `select distinct` to a `group by` and then uses conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
SELECT V.visitdate AS DATE), COUNT(*) AS TotalDistinctIPs,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CustomerIPs,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FirstVisits
FROM (SELECT ip, [type], CAST(V.visitdate AS DATE) as VisitDate,
             row_number() over (partition by ip order by CAST(V.visitdate AS DATE)) as seqnum
      FROM IP_Addresses V
      GROUP BY ip, [type], CAST(V.visitdate AS DATE)
     ) v
GROUP BY V.visitdate
ORDER BY V.visitdate DESC;
```

Comment: Missing a , after visitdate and the 4th line and have a ) after date in first line that shouldn't be there. And results don't match requested results.  I'm not sure if this is because the OP results are incorrect of this is yet.

Comment: I don't think this output is correct. 29/05/14 should have 0 'New Customers' or 'First Visits' because 192.168.0.4 is NOT Type C and 192.168.0.5 was a visitor on 2014-05-25. Is your query is always going to return 1 First Visit per day?

Comment: @h4ng4r18 . . . I don't know exactly what the logic is (since your question doesn't clarify it).  It is possible that you want `where seqnum = 1 and [type] = 'C'`.

Comment: To keep the example simple - I haven't posted the original query. there are other sums running from this derived query where type can vary. It seems that a where clause might somehow tidy it up.

I stated the desired output in the question with some reasoning?...

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff and xQbert for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing COUNT(*) to COUNT(1) saves some time in a query.  Have you tried that?